# How to find project references contained in ".project" file using eclipse API?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In an eclipse plugin, I have a function that search projects referenced by a project and add them to the classpath. The problem is: when project references change we must change the classpath to remove unnecessary dependencies. So I used the method IProject.GetReferencedProject() to recreate the dependencies of the classpath, but this method returns not only the projects contained in ".project" but also in the ". classpath". So if a dependency is added to the classpath even after deleting the reference to the project(".project" is updated), the classpath entry to project is recreated because it figure in the result of the method GetReferencedProject.
I need a way to search referenced project ".project" and not in ".classpath".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
IProject.getProjectDescription().getReferencedProjects()
```